# Conditional operator with INT

Tags: conditional-operator

How do I write this if statement with conditional operator?

```
int TopicID = ...
int LastPost = ...

if (LastPost == 0) 
{
    LastPost = TopicID
} else 
{
    LastPost = LastPost;
}
```

I tried this:

```
LastPost == 0 ? LastPost == TopicID : LastPost == LastPost;
```

But it didn't work so as you can see im not really that pro.. :P

Comment: What you tried is called a [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LastPost = (LastPost == 0 ? TopicID : LastPost);
```

Anyway, what is the sense of assigning `LastPost` to itself? Just remove your whole `else` block and you'll have the simplest way for what you're trying to achieve.